# Parsing Expression Tree To Sqlstring - Not Reinventing the wheel

Tags: sql, string, linq, parsing, expression-trees

I need to parse an expressiontree to get a sql where clause.

Aren't there any classes in the .NET FX or any third party library which already have this abilities ?

I mean Linq2SQL, EntityFramework , all of them have to do this, so does anyone know, if there is something that can be reused instead of reinventing the wheel?

```
MyType.Where(Func<TEntity,bool>((entity)=>entity.Id == 5)))
```

now i need to get the corresponding string representing a where clause:

```
 where abc.Id = "5"
```

this is just an simple example. it should also work with logical conjunctions.

I know I can create the expressiontree and parse it on my own, but i think there could be something already existing, which I'm missing

Comment: No

I've a methoed like this 

MyType.Where(Func<TEntity,bool>((entity)=>entity.Id == 5)))

now i need to get the corresponding string representing a where clause:
where abc.Id = "5"

For this I could created an expression tree and parse it on my own.
But I feel, that there should be something already existing

Comment: Ah, okay. Perhaps you can edit your original question and add that extra info in there?

Answer (score 5):

You could create an [`ExpressionVisitor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor.aspx) with the sole purpose of finding and processing the where calls.  Making this task very easy to handle.

e.g.,

```cs
public class WhereCallVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
    {
        var method = node.Method;
        if (method.Name == "Where" && method.DeclaringType == typeof(Queryable))
        {   // we are in a Queryable.Where() call
            ProcessWhereCall(node);
        }
        return base.VisitMethodCall(node);
    }

    private void ProcessWhereCall(MethodCallExpression whereCall)
    {
        // extract the predicate expression
        var predicateExpr = ((dynamic)whereCall.Arguments[1]).Operand as LambdaExpression;
        // do stuff with predicateExpr
    }
    // p.s., dynamic used here to simplify the extraction
}
```

Then to use it:

```cs
var query = from row in table
            where row.Foo == "Bar"
            select row.Baz;
var visitor = new WhereCallVisitor();
visitor.Visit(query.Expression);
```

Comment: I hope I'm not off base with this answer.  As I understood the question, given an expression tree, you want to find the where calls and do something with the predicates (create an SQL string that represents the clause).  This alone wouldn't be _the_ answer but it will get you there without too much problems.  Upon finding the predicate expression, it should be relatively easy getting the corresponding SQL string.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Thats how I planned to implement it. But I thought there would exist something out of the box.

But it looks like theres nothing an I've to implement it.